# Why does the following styling not work in firefox? (it works in all other browsers)

Tags: asp.net, html, css, firefox3.6

Edit: The copyright message does not appear on screen, but it is there in the HTML source of the Firefox window!

ASP.NET page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="learnvb1._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Welcome to</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"  runat="server">
        <div id="main_holder">
          <center>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Copyright &copy 2011 blah blah. All rights reserved."></asp:Label>
          </center>
        </div><!-- main_holder div ends -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

StyleSheet1.css

```
body 
{
    background-color:Black;
}    
#main_holder
{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:95%;
    padding-top:0.3%;
    background-color:Yellow;
    color:Green;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Firefox HTML:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>
    Welcome to
</title><link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>        
    <span id="Label2">Browser Capabilities
Type = Firefox3.6.13
Name = Firefox
Version = 3.6.13
Major Version = 3
Minor Version = 0.6
Platform = WinXP
Is Beta = False
Is Crawler = False
Is AOL = False
Is Win16 = False
Is Win32 = True
Supports Frames = True
Supports Tables = True
Supports Cookies = True
Supports VBScript = False
Supports JavaScript = 1.4
Supports Java Applets = True
Supports ActiveX Controls = False
Supports JavaScript Version = 
</span>        
     <div id="main_holder">   
              <center>
        <span id="Label1">Copyright © 2011 blah and blah and blah. All rights reserved.</span>
        </center>
    </div>
    <!-- main_holder div ends -->           
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work without position:fixed for the #main_holder?

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML source rather than the ASPX source?

Comment: One thing that might be causing issues is that the entity you are using for the copyright symbol is malformed. It should be `&copy;` and not `&copy`.

Comment: @Chris thanks corrected but no difference,  and html actual added

Comment: @john yes but, the page appears twice as large in height.. but this only in fire fox

Comment: I created a fiddle - it might help http://jsfiddle.net/fQ8sh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you add this CSS:

```
html,  body { height: 100%; padding: 0; }
```

And replace `margin-top: 95%` in your #main_holder CSS with `bottom: 0;`, like so:

```
#main_holder {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    padding-top:0.3%;
    background-color:Yellow;
    color:Green;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fQ8sh/2/

Comment: That seems to create a scrollbar for me on the main page, even if the content is actually not even filling up the whole page. Is that because it is adding the bars height onto the 100% when calculating the size for scrollbars or something crazy like that?

Comment: Sorry, you should reset the padding on the body attribute too. I've amended the answer above.

Comment: Perfect now. +1. :) Though you may want to update your fiddle+link.